# How to get dictinct userid with order by close

Tags: sql-server, select, sql-order-by

I have table called info, and its data something like this,

```
+----------+-------------------------+------+
| FKUserID |      CompletedTime      | Type |
+----------+-------------------------+------+
| 1        | 2021-03-10 12:56:00.423 | 5    |
+----------+-------------------------+------+
| 245      | 2021-03-10 12:46:46.977 | 5    |
+----------+-------------------------+------+
| 1        | 2021-03-10 12:44:53.683 | 5    |
+----------+-------------------------+------+
| 1        | 2021-03-10 12:40:54.733 | 5    |
+----------+-------------------------+------+
| 1        | 2021-03-10 12:35:26.307 | 5    |
+----------+-------------------------+------+
| 245      | 2021-03-10 11:11:33.887 | 5    |
+----------+-------------------------+------+
| 245      | 2021-03-10 10:18:11.403 | 5    |
+----------+-------------------------+------+
```

I need to get distinct userID  data, and also with the maximum completed time of theirs `CompletedTime`  column

expected output is,

```
+----------+-------------------------+------+
| FKUserID |      CompletedTime      | Type |
+----------+-------------------------+------+
| 1        | 2021-03-10 12:56:00.423 | 5    |
+----------+-------------------------+------+
| 245      | 2021-03-10 12:46:46.977 | 5    |
+----------+-------------------------+------+
```

**Updated: sorry I need to do this Linq query as well**

Comment: Is this a SQL question or a Linq question?  You should be asking only for one.  Please remove the irrelevant tags.

Comment: What do you want to happen with the `Type` column

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using `ROW_NUMBER` along with `TOP 1 WITH TIES` for this type of problem:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *
FROM info
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FKUserID ORDER BY CompletedTime DESC);
```

Comment: How can I write this using linq query

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp
Grouping by User Id and using `Max()` on CompletedTime, you'll reach your result.

Your SQL will look like

```
SELECT `FKUserID`, MAX(`CompletedTime`) from `TableName` GROUP BY `FKUserID`;
```

Comment: How can I do this using linq